# SNAP advisories about future dependency changes

Tags: php, dependencies, snap

I just installed the [Nextcloud snap](https://snapcraft.io/nextcloud) in Ubuntu 19.10; all went well. The [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) application contains all the necessary functions to upgrade itself and the apps; those work well.

One of the apps announces that it will no longer support PHP v7.2 in the future. The OS is already at the newest version, but apparently is not used by the snap.

How do I upgrade PHP inside a snap package or am I at the mercy of the package developer?

Comment: You don't update the snap yourself at all.  You wait for the Snap to be updated/upgraded.  At that time when its rebuilt they can provide the higher PHP dependency which will be shipped with it when the snap is built and released.  Then you do `sudo snap refresh` to update your snaps against the Snap Store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the Nextcloud snap bundles everything it needs, including PHP v7.2. v7.2 is still supported and receiving regular updates, and the snap maintainers (disclaimer: that's me) don't typically introduce changes without a reason. However, v7.2 will reach the [end of active support](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) in a month, which is probably why the app you mention notes that it will no longer support it soon. It will continue receiving security updates for a good while, but barring any issues, the snap [will upgrade to v7.3 soon](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/issues/1149). You'll receive that update automatically.

In the future, you should directly notify the maintainers of issues like this, for example by logging an issue against the project. You can find the appropriate place by using `snap info <snap name>`, e.g.:

```
$ snap info nextcloud
<snip>
contact:   https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap
```

Comment: I'm new to snaps. I thought it was something I could do myself.

Comment: Not typically, no. Snaps bundle their dependencies. This isn't to put you at the mercy of the maintainer, but to make sure that what the maintainer tests is exactly byte-for-byte for what the users have. As a maintainer, I don't have to deal with people trying to use incompatible stuff, I just make it work and keep the updates flowing.

Comment: +1 for directing OP to file report with developer. It spares us less-informed from reading the question and allows OP to get response direct from the horse's mouse, so to speak...

Comment: @Kyle So ten different apps might use the same 10 MB of libraries, and they are installed 10 times to consume 100 MB?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. In practice, it's not 100MB since snaps are squashfs images and are compressed on disk, but there are indeed ten copies. We're getting a smidge off topic here, and comments are pretty limiting. It might be worth asking some questions in https://forum.snapcraft.io/ or hopping in #snappy on Freenode IRC. There are good reasons for the duplication.